# ReadItemAsync of Container cannot parse Stack<T> instance correctly

Tags: c#, stack, azure-cosmosdb

As it is known, Stack instance represents last-in-first-out (LIFO) collection.

```
Stack<ChangeItem> ChangeItems = new Stack<ChangeItem>();
ChangeItems.Push(changeItem);
```

After serialized into Cosmos DB, last-in item is at position 0. The sequence is correct.

But the problem is when the instance is retrieved back from DB.

`response = await container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, partitionKey);`

The sequence is reversed. It becomes first-in-first-out sequence.
Then add new item, and save back, the last item is at the first position. Eventually the sequence is mess.

For example,

The first time to save the Stack instance, the sequence is [1, 2]

Then retrieving instance back, the sequence becomes [2, 1], add new item, the sequence is [3, 1, 2]

Then retrieving instance back, the sequence becomes [2, 1, 3], add new item, the sequence is [4, 2, 1, 3]

...
[image: Mess sequence]

Is there any setting to avoid the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that your desired order is to sort by a property value like `OccurredOn`, I'd suggest using a [SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netcore-3.1) instead of Stack. Assuming your model class is defined correctly for comparison, your app would sort them automatically in memory and should be persisted consistently.

Comment: I will test with SortedSet later. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation with Stacks where the order changes to backwards when you serialize and deserialize the Stack. I would suggest using more of a flat list List which serialized and deserializes nicely in the same order. Also, you can use LINQ to order by dates.